# UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor and keychain access in Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, keychain

Our old app was written in ObjectiveC. The new app is a Xamarin app. Both app have the same bundle identifier.

When upgrading from the old app to the new one I encounter some problems.
To upgrade, I install the old app from the appstore and then deploy the new app from Xamarin Studio over it.

When the app first runs, it accesses the `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor` and needs to read some data from the app's keychain.
When calling `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor` in the Xamarin app, I get a different GUID than the one I get in the old ObjectiveC app.
I am also not able to access the values stored by the old app in the keychain.
This is the code I am using to get the IdentifierForVendor:

`UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString()`

This is the code I'm using to access the keychain:

```
        SecStatusCode code;
        // Query the record.
        SecRecord queryRec = new SecRecord ( SecKind.GenericPassword ) { Service = serviceId, Account = username, Synchronizable = synchronizable };
        queryRec = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord ( queryRec, out code );

        // If found, try to get password.
        if ( code == SecStatusCode.Success && queryRec != null && queryRec.Generic != null )
        {
            // Decode from UTF8.
            return NSString.FromData ( queryRec.Generic, NSStringEncoding.UTF8 );
        }
```

```

Comment: You can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76126629/ios-devices-unique-persistent-identifier-changes-whenever-the-app-is-uninstalle/76818242#76818242