# iOS device's unique persistent identifier changes whenever the app is uninstalled and reinstalled on the device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The iOS device's unique persistent identifier changes whenever the app is uninstalled and reinstalled on the device.
iOS puts serious restrictions on unique persistent identifiers because of privacy concerns.

How can I get a unique, fixed identification ID?

I'm trying this code, but after I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it, my unique ID changed.

```
var uuidKey = new NSString("myDeviceUUID");

    string bundleId = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier;
    string uuid = null;

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0))
    {
        uuid = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();
    }
    else
    {
        uuid = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(uuidKey);
    }
    if (uuid == null)
    {
        uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    string uniqueId = $"{bundleId}-{uuid}";

    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(uuid, uuidKey);           
    Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["DeviceId"] = uniqueId;
    Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Comment: Why would you need a unique id? If I buy a new phone, I get a new ID, too. Yet it's still me on my phone. Wouldn't it make more sense to identify the user, by a login or other means?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to store the FCM token in the database, but the problem is that when an app is uninstalled and installed, the FCM token is changed, so I want to replace the FCM token with the same device ID. But in iOS devices ID is changed always @nvoigt

Comment: What do you need that for? All you need is a list of all devices, their FCM tokens and which user each belongs too. Devices will register and unregister all the time, you don't need to keep track if something was the same hardware.

Comment: FCM token is generated when the app is installed; at that time, I have no userid @nvoigt

Comment: I'm just saying that you have to handle that scenario anyway. People can and will have multiple devices and switch devices. So if you have to write that code, it can easily handle the "switched identifiers, but I know it's the same hardware device" anyway. You are thinking about a solution for a very specific case, that will be redundant once you solve the whole problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you; i need to think this through @nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this by utilising the keychain of iOS.

How this works? We will check whether a existing keychain with our key exists in the device, in this case that will hold the unique Vendor ID provided by Apple. If that exists which means that the app is already installed before in the device and user is re-installing it. So we get the Unique Vendor ID from the Keychain we stored earlier. If the key does not exists, which means that this user is newly installing the app for the first time in the device, so we will store our unique vendor id into the keychain for later access.

NOTE: Keychain data will not be delete if the app is uninstalled.

Add this code in `AppDeletegate.cs` and call this method before `FinishedLaunching`.

`SecureStorage` is a `Xamarin.Essentials` package.

You can use the dependency service to read the `UID`. In here `Helpers.DeviceInfo.UID` is a static string with variable name `UID` located in a `DeviceInfo` class under `Helpers` namespace in `Xamarin.iOS` folder.

```
/**
     * For iOS devices, for each uninstall and install, there will be a
     * new vendor ID is generated. So in order to identify the device
     * uniquely, we are storing the Vendor Id given by Apple in the
     * device keychain. So if the keychain does not have the unique
     * vendor Id, then we are adding one into the keychain store.
     */
    private async void PrepareVendorIdentifier()
    {
        try
        {
            string uid = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("AppVendorID");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid))
            {
                uid = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();
                await SecureStorage.SetAsync("AppVendorID", uid);
            }

            Helpers.DeviceInfo.UID = uid;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Helpers.DeviceInfo.UID = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.